# Getting checked checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a function that is supposed to catch changes to all checkboxes. It works when the boxes are clicked manually, but does not work when the `toggleAll()` function triggers them.

Anyway to correct this?

```
$(function() {
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
    if ( this.checked ) {
        alert(this.id+' is checked');
    } else {
        alert(this.id+' is not checked');
    }
    });
});

function toggleAll() {
    var selectAllCheckbox = $("#selectAllCheckbox");
    if ( selectAllCheckbox.prop('checked') ) {
        // uncheck them all
        $("[id^=friendRequestCheckbox]").attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        // check them all
        $("[id^=friendRequestCheckbox]").attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

I am running an old version of jQuery and have not updated to the new version including `prop`, just in case that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing elements programmatically, you also have to trigger the event programmatically. Try :

```
$("[id^=friendRequestCheckbox]").trigger('change')
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple and elegant solution. Will mark as answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks for the prompt answer.